# Convert UTM to decimal degree in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, coordinates, utm

I am using the following code in R to convert my UTM coordinates to decimal degrees

```
utmcoor<-SpatialPoints(cbind(starling2$Easting,starling2$Northing), proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=51"))
longlatcoor<-spTransform(utmcoor,CRS("+proj=longlat"))
```

how to I add the results ('latlongcoor' output) as two new columns in my original dataframe 'starling2'?

Answer (score 1):

In a SpatialPointsDataFrame the coordinates behave like the "rownames" for your data:

```
starling2$X <- coordinates(longlatcoor)[,1]
starling2$y <- coordinates(longlatcoor)[,2]
```